# Detect click events on a d3 brush (v4)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, event-handling, mouseevent

I would like to run a javascript function when the selected region of a d3-brush is clicked on (or double clicked on). I would also like to understand exactly why my naive approach below does not work.

The d3-brush creates two rects: one of class selection, which is the currently selected brush region, and one of class overlay, which covers the maximum possible extent of the brush.

I am able to detect `mousedown` events on both of those objects, I am only able to detect `click` (or `dblclick`) events on the overlay, and I cannot detect `mouseup` events on either:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg")
var g = svg.append("g")
var brush = d3.brush()

var brushGroup = g.append("g")
    .call(brush)

brushGroup.selectAll(".overlay")
    .on("mousedown", () => console.log('mousedown on overlay'))
    .on("click", () => console.log('click on overlay'))
    .on("mouseup", () => console.log('mouseup on overlay'))
  
brushGroup.selectAll(".selection")
    .on("mousedown", () => console.log('mousedown on selection'))
    .on("click", () => console.log('click on selection'))
    .on("mouseup", () => console.log('mouseup on selection'))
```

```html
<svg width="300" height="200">
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="none" stroke="gray"></rect>
</svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

I would like to understand this inconsistency. I know vaguely that this has to do with d3-brush v4 'consuming' or 'stopping propagation' of certain events in certain situations. But I cannot find documentation of which and when.

I realize that I need to get my handling of the event in there before d3 consumes it. But I have no idea how to do this, and I haven't been able to track down an example of this.

I also cannot find the relevant portion of the d3 source. I have grep'd for `click` and `dblclick` in d3-brush and d3-selection and found nothing relevant. So even being pointed the right code would help my understanding.

Comment: Found [this](https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom/issues/66) on the d3 github in issues. The zoom/brush does consume some of the events (one of which is mouseup, super annoying sometimes)

Comment: Thanks, I took a look over that but couldn't get any of Mike's workarounds to work. All of the specific advice seems to revolve around the zoom functionality, not the drag/brush. I've even modified the d3 code to try and disable the event consumption, but things still don't work how I expect..